# Enforce regex on fieldset field - ExtJS

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs

How do I enforce RegEx on a field item in a fieldset?
For example, in the code below, there is a `Country` field, but I need to enforce the regex checking when the textbox goes out of focus. The idea is to use `Ext.ApplyIf`, but wondering how could I do that?

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'About You',
            instructions: 'Tell us all about yourself',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'firstName',
                    label: 'First Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'lastName',
                    label: 'Last Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'country',
                    label: 'Country',
                    regex: /^[A-Z]{2}$/,
                    regexText: 'Two letter country code (ISO 3166-1 alpha 2 standard) (eg:NO)!',
                    allowBlank: false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From `fullscreen: true` i guess this is extjs modern.

In extjs modern you can only listen to `focus` event, there isn't event like `focusleave` (which exists in extjs classic toolkit).
In extjs modern also textfield hasn't parameters like regex and regexText.

You can't do this with core extjs-field functionalities.

Look at [Ext.field.Text](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.field.Text.html) definition.